# Why use `eventEmitter` instead of promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, eventemitter

I've found the following example in a book I'm reading:

```
function User() {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
    this.addUser = function (username, password) {
        // add the user
        // then emit an event
        this.emit("userAdded", username, password);
    };
}

var user = new User();
var username = "colin";
var password = "password";

user.on("userAdded", function(username, password) {
    console.log("Added user " + username);
});

user.addUser(username, password);
```

It seems to me that using EventEmitter is completely redundant here. Promises would do a much better job:

```
function User() {
    this.addUser = function (username, password) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            // add the user
            // and resolve
            resolve();
        });
    };
}
```

and the usage:

```
user.addUser(username, password).then(function(username, password) {
    console.log("Added user " + username);
});
```

Does using `EventEmitter` have any advantages over using `Promises` or it's simply the code from the time when Promises where not available? Or is this style is not welcomed in `node.js`?

Comment: What if you want to be notified when multiple users are added with the same hanfler? `Promise`'s wont work there. A promise can only be resolved with a value once.

Comment: As for me, main differences between EventEmitter and Promise  in point, that Promise  can be fulfilled  only once whereas events can be triggered any number of times.

Answer (score 10):

Main differences between EventEmitter and Promise in point, that Promise can be fulfilled only once whereas events can be triggered any number of times

Answer (score -1):

I do not understand in which scenario it becomes reality what Denis wrote. Each time addUser is called, a new promise is returned. In event driven logic a new event is triggered.
Main difference I see is that a promise, whilst more performant (in my experience), is sort of "local". You have singular linear path from where method was called. Meanwhile when using events, you can have multiple other components listen to the event. So each time a user gets added, all of them get notified and run their logic. Another thing is that with events you can define what happens once and then no matter where the method which triggers the event is called, the event listener callback fires.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32487498)